# How can I properly simulate percentage columns without using percentage (given the container width)?

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, multiple-columns

I'm trying to make a particular type of CSS layout, like this (which works). Please note that I'm not using the Stack Overflow built-in code editor only because it lacks [SCSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sass_%28stylesheet_language%29) support:

https://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/NWYZwex

As asked in comments, I'll also add a compiled CSS version, but I really think you should watch it on [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen) since it also have a big screen that is currently needed to really see what happens:

```css
.main-container {
  max-width: none;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #777;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5);
  gap: 4em;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: calc(458px - 2em);
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(50vw + 114.5px - 2em);
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <!-- <div class="inner-container"> -->

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column left">
        left
      </div>
      <div class="column right">
        right
      </div>
    </div><!-- cols -->

  <!-- </div> --><!-- inner -->

</div>
```

The above is for the bleeding edge right column. Basically, given a centered 'underlying' or 'ghost' container of 1145 pixels, I want a 40% column and a bleeding edge column, with a gap of 4em.  Above, I was able to do it.

The columns should be 'aligned' with other similar components that are using a common flex-basis approach, 40% and 60%. But I found that, compared to that normal flex-basis layout, the above solution is not working perfect. Here, I'm trying another similar approach, but the results are the same: columns are not perfectly aligned with the standard flex layout:

https://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/PoeNPMz

As asked in comments, I'll also add a compiled CSS version, but I really think you should watch it on CodePen since it also have a big screen that is currently needed to really see what happens:

```css
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  max-width: none;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
}

.inner-container {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(50vw + 572.5px);
  background-color: #080;
}

.columns {
  display: flex;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 200, 0.5);
  gap: 4em;
  background-color: #005;
}

.left {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  width: calc(458px - 2em );
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
  height: 100px;
  width: calc(687px - 2em );
  background-color: red;
}

.post-slideshow {
  height: 50px;
  width: calc(50vw + 114.5px - 2em);
  background-color: #ffd736;
}

.main-container2 {
  max-width: none;
  margin-left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  margin-right: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  background-color: #c3c3c3;
}

.columns2 {
  display: flex;
  width: 1145px;
  gap: 4em;
  background-color: #050;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.left2 {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: cyan;
  flex-basis: 40%;
}

.right2 {
  text-align: left;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">

  <div class="inner-container">

    <div class="columns">
      <div class="column left">
        left
      </div>
      <div class="column right">
        <div class="post-slideshow">test</div>
      </div>
    </div><!-- cols -->

  </div><!-- inner -->

</div>


<div class="main-container2">

  <div class="inner-container2">

    <div class="columns2">
      <div class="column left2">
        left regular flex basis layout
      </div>
      <div class="column right2">
        right regular flex basis layout
      </div>
    </div><!-- cols -->

  </div><!-- inner -->

</div>
```

Just take a look to the cyan columns. For example, the following will result in something slightly less than flex-basis: 40%

```
$container-max-width: 1145px;
$gap: 4em;
width: calc(#{$container-max-width / 100 * 40} - #{$gap / 2} );
```

Why doesn't it work? Essentially, I think it could depend on how browsers calculate rendering of flex-basis elements. I don't know...

Comment: In 'Variante' you forgot to subtract 2em (half of gap) from 'left2' and 'right2' flex-basis. `gap` add to total width of an element.

Comment: @RenevanderLende thank you! this one works: https://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/LYmNyXO, but what if I couldn't substract 2em from flex-basis? (wordpress doesn't do). If I don't, and avoid substracting it to 'left' and 'right' too, it won't work. Why? (https://codepen.io/stratboy/pen/JjvXJNZ)

Comment: I always try to avoid using either `margin` or `gap` by creating wrapper containers with padding and put the content container inside a wrapper. With `box-sizing: border-box` this works out nicely and forementioned spacing subtraction will no longer be needed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, [RenevanderLende's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73662981/how-can-i-properly-simulate-percentage-columns-without-using-percentage-given-t#comment130080789_73662981) solved the issue: subtract 2em (half of gap) from 'left2' and 'right2' flex-basis. It is important here that 'gap add to total width of an element'. That was the key.